# Find integral of $\frac{e^x}{1+e^x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I found $\displaystyle\int\displaystyle\frac{e^x}{1+e^x}dx= -\ln\left|1+e^x\right|+C$ in my text book, but I want to know how the minus sign comes there.

Please anybody explain to me.

Comment: Use $$u = 1 + e^x.$$

Comment: There shouldn't be a minus sign there.

Comment: Try to use Latex. It makes questions readable. You can check @Nameless' comment for how to use it.

Answer (score 6):

There is not a minus sign in the integral; rather, we have

$$\int \frac{e^x}{1 + e^x} dx = \ln(1 + e^x) + C$$

This can be checked by differentiating:

$$\frac{d}{dx} \ln(1 + e^x) = \frac{1}{1 + e^x} \frac{d}{dx} (1 + e^x) = \frac{e^x}{1 + e^x}$$ as desired.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

You could notice that the numerator $e^x$ is just the derivative of the denominator ($1+e^x$) so you have to integrate $\frac{u'(x)}{u(x)}$ and then the result.